# can the source code for video slot machine be pulled using dev tools?

Tags: game-hacking, pe-resources

i want to obtain pre built  source code and logic for video slots , and then rename my own sprites / skins, ect and essentially create a reskin of said game .  can anyone tell me how this can be accomplished?